# how to pass whole keyword into for loop variable | linux |

Tags: for-loop, sh

i have a scenario where i want to pass the entire keyword to the for loop when i cat file

The file contain below data : demo.txt

```
$ABC=RAM
$$PQR='RAJ'
SKY is blue
flower '/d/m'
```

**my code :**

```
for i in `cat demo.txt`
do 
    echo $i
done
```

The `$i` is not taking entire row as a keyword :     `SKY is blue` or `flower '/d/m'`

**my output :**

```
my demo :  $ABC=RAM
my demo :  $$PQR='RAJ'
my demo :  SKY     
my demo :  is      
my demo :  blue    
my demo :  flower  
my demo :  '/d/m'
```

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to read the file line by line, and get each complete (untouched) line in a variable, right? Then try this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf "Line read is >%s<\n" "$line"
done < demo.txt
```